# Add ACF custom field in WooCommerce Checkout Form (Gutenberg Block)

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, wordpress-gutenberg, acfpro

Recently I noticed that WooCommerce checkout form/page is now being generated by Gutenberg blocks. All the available hooks / templates isn't working anymore in this new page! Any idea how I can use Advanced Custom Fields pro to add fields in the checkout form?

Tried creating custom Gutenberg blocks using ACF pro, but they aren't showing up on WooCommerce Checkout page. Also, tried directly adding ACF fields into that page, but they aren't placing inside the Checkout form. I've also tried to add custom field from functions.php still it's not appearing in the checkout form.